# Printing in python a C++ class using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Let's say one has such a class

```
class Data
{
   public:
      Data(double d): value_(d) {};

   private:
      double value_;
 };
```

Is it possible to export it in Python with pybind11 such that

```
d = Data(3.14)
print(d)
```

displays 3.14 instead of something like

> Data object at 0x7fed8a8c3298

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this when you export:

```
class_<Data>("Data", module)
    .def("__repr__", [](const Data& d){ return std::to_string(d.getValue()); });
```

Notice I added that `getValue` method since `value_` is private.  Though depending on your interface, it might make more sense to add something like `Data::toString()` instead.

http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#binding-lambda-functions